# Tool for organizing language courses for Ukrainian refugees wanted

Tags: collaboration

I am looking for a tool to organize language courses for Ukrainian refugees with the following features:

- An overview of the language courses offered.
- Interested people should be able to select the language course they want to attend and provide some personal information (ideally, it should be possible to validate the data entered)
- It should be possible to set a maximum number of registrations
- The entered data should be stored in Europe and the provider must meet the DPP/DSGVO requirements

I know MS Forms (http://forms.office.com) which more or less meets the requirements (at least partially), but maybe you know a better tool for this use case.

I am looking forward to your suggestions .

Comment: Welcome Marc!  Given that you are trying to help people, you earned an instant upvote from me.  Again, welcome to our community, and we look forward to your future posts.

Comment: BTW, it might be helpful to explain, in your answer, in a little more detail about what you mean by "organize language courses".  Also, specifying whether you are looking for recommendations for gratis or paid software will hopefully help get you the answers you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) for your use cases. PollUnit is a poll maker with various types of polls like [votings](https://pollunit.com/en/voting), [surveys](https://pollunit.com/en/survey), [tables](https://pollunit.com/en/table). When you create a voting, you can specify what to vote on. This includes free text, date, time, images, etc.

Here a example of a scheduling:

[image]

**To your requirements:**

> An overview of the language courses offered.

The PollUnit type [Landing Page](https://pollunit.com/en/landing-page) can collect polls / scheduling and show an overview of all what you are offering.

> Interested people should be able to select the language course they
> want to attend and provide some personal information (ideally, it
> should be possible to validate the data entered)

In the advanced step when creating a PollUnit you can require additional information from your participants. These are only visible to admins. (Premium required)

> It should be possible to set a maximum number of registrations

In the advanced step when creating a PollUnit of the type voting you can define a limit per option. So you could also set a different number of seats per option / date / time. (Premium required)

> The entered data should be stored in Europe and the provider must meet
> the DPP/DSGVO requirements

All servers are located in the EU. PollUnit meats the GDPR and also offer an DPA for signing online.

**Additional information:**

PollUnit is available ass freemium. The basic functions for up to 40 participants are free of charge.

PollUnit offers discount for nonprofit organizations. If the features help you, write to the PollUnit Support.

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit.

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you for the proposal and the detailed response. I had a look at the homepage and at PollUnit. Unfortunately I couldn't find an example/screenshots which illustrate how a poll for a language course or seminar could look like. I was also not able to test the advanced features in a test mode. Is that possible before buying a license?

Comment: You need to register a free account and send a mail to support@pollunit.com.

Comment: If you want a tabular view of available courses you could create something like the image I have attached in my answer. You can also switch to a list view or a survey like poll.